# TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' during .match()

Tags: typescript

In the below code, I am getting the title error linting on `fileNameMatches[0]`. It does not lint on the `Boolean()` check. Removing that check doesn't fix or change anything. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
protected getLocalFilename(): string {
  const fileNameMatches: string[]|null = this.filePath.match(/\/(.+\.js)$`/);
  
  if (Boolean(fileNameMatches) && fileNameMatches[0] !== null) { // TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
    return fileNameMatches[0]; // TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
  }
  else {
    throw Error("No filename found during regex matching")
  }
}
```

**Also tried**

```
if (typeOf fileNameMatches !== "null") {
```

This test also returns the `"Object is possibly 'null'"` error.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using the `!` operator to assert not null on `fileNameMatches![0]`:

```js
protected getLocalFilename(): string {
  const fileNameMatches: string[] | null = this.filePath.match(/\/(.+\.js)$`/);
  
  if (Boolean(fileNameMatches)) { 
    return fileNameMatches![0];
  }
  else {
    throw Error("No filename found during regex matching")
  }
}
```